# Convertir los valores de un arbol binario de busqueda en una array ordenado

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando resolver el siguiente ejercicio, pero me cuesta entender cómo haría la recursión para recorrer el árbol, ya que el parámetro que recibe la función es la propia array que tengo que llenar. O lo estoy entendiendo mal?

Este es el ejercicio:
Implementar el metodo 'toArray' en el prototype del BinarySearchTree
que devuelva los valores del arbol en una array ordenado
Ejemplo:
32
8   64
5       9
resultado:[5,8,9,32,64]

BinarySearchTree.prototype.toArray = function (queue = []) {
/* Tu código aquí */
Intenté con esto, sé que está mal y que no tiene mucho sentido, pero no sé cómo se hace:

```
 if(this.value){
    queue.push(this.value)
  } else {
    return []
  }

  while(this.left){
     queue.push(this.left.toArray(queue = []))
  }
  while(this.right){
     queue.push(this.right.toArray(queue = []))
  }
  return queue
```

Espero que puedan explicarme. Gracias.

Comment: Entiendo que debes devolver el parámetro de tipo array que te pasan, ordenarlo (descendente o ascendente) y devolver el array ordenado. Ej: convertir el parámetro `[1,3,2,5,4]` en `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: Hola @PauloUrbanoRivera, sí, algo así. Pero los valores vienen de un árbol binario de búsqueda. Tengo que tomar los valores del árbol y ordenarlos.

Comment: Intenté dibujar el árbol para que se entienda, pero no me deja stackoverflow. Pero para que se den una idea el root es 32, a la izquierda tiene un 8 y a la derecha 64, a la izquierda del 8 hay un 5 y a su derecha un 9. Entonces la funcion debería devolver la array [5,8,9,32,64]

Comment: Sería muy bueno que incluyeras un ejemplo de la forma en que vendrian los datos.. como string, como array, etc..